# Cygwin SVN symbolic link checkout broken

Tags: svn, cygwin, symlink

I've installed the latest version of Cygwin on Vista with SVN, Make and GCC in the installation. When I SVN checkout from a repository with some symbolic links in it, the symbolic links are not converted to symbolic links on Cygwin, rather they are just left as regular ascii files with "link ../../blah/blah" inside them.

SVN proplist of the symbolic link files says they are svn:special and when I check out from the same repository on Ubuntu it all works as desired.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're running Cygwin's `svn`? (you can check with '`which svn`')

If you happen to be running the win32 `svn.exe` you'll get the win32 behavior on Cygwin as well (happened to me).